# Getting Configuration Values when Using Application Factory

Tags: python, flask

I want to check some config before running a view, so I wrote a decorator for it.  However, I can't get the config because I'm using the application factory pattern, so the app isn't set up yet when defining the decorator.  I get related to working out of the application context.

How do I access the config if I don't have the app yet?

```
from flask import Flask
from views import blueprint

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DECORATOR_KEY'] = 'decorator-key-here'
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`decorators.py`:

```
import functools
from flask import current_app

DECORATOR_KEY = current_app.config.get('DECORATOR_KEY')

def key_length():
    return len(DECORATOR_KEY)

def config_decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Key Length: {}".format(key_length())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

`views.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/')
@config_decorator
def main():
    return "This is the only route."
```

```
File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from views import blueprint
  File "/Users/pat/Code/Playground/FactoryProblem/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from decorators import config_decorator
  File "/Users/pat/Code/Playground/FactoryProblem/decorators.py", line 6, in <module>
    DECORATOR_KEY = current_app.config.get('DECORATOR_KEY')
  File "/Users/pat/.virtualenvs/factory/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/pat/.virtualenvs/factory/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/pat/.virtualenvs/factory/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `current_app` outside an app context, but you're using `DECORATOR_KEY = current_app.config.get('DECORATOR_KEY')` at the top level of a module.  Move that to inside the decorator wrapper.

```
def key_length():
    DECORATOR_KEY = current_app.config['DECORATOR_KEY']
    return len(DECORATOR_KEY)

def config_decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Key Length: {}".format(key_length())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```